# How to store parsedArray data to SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am getting string data by calling an API.

```
 JArray parsedArray = JArray.Parse(stringData);
 int i = 1;

 foreach (var item in parsedArray)
 {
     ProjectInformation aProjectInformation = new ProjectInformation();

     string id = (string)item.SelectToken("formid");
     aProjectInformation.FormId = id;

     string projectName = (string)item.SelectToken("title");
     aProjectInformation.ProjectName = projectName;

     string surveyName = (string)item.SelectToken("description");
     aProjectInformation.SurveyName = surveyName;

     string lastSubmissionTime = (string)item.SelectToken("last_submission_time");
     aProjectInformation.LastSubmissionTime = lastSubmissionTime;

     int submissionNumber = (int)item.SelectToken("num_of_submissions");
     aProjectInformation.TotalSubmission = submissionNumber;

     int submissionToday = (int)item.SelectToken("submission_count_for_today");
     aProjectInformation.SubmissionToday = submissionToday;

     aProjectInformation.Serial = i;
     projectList.Add(aProjectInformation);

     i++;
}
```

How can I store id, projectname, surveyname, lastsubmissiontime, submissionnumber, submissiontoday, serial to a table of a SQL Server database?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to store in database? Show what you have tried and tell what did not behave as expected. If you are totally stumped with database communication then do a search for ADO.net

Comment: ADO.net is a bit low level.. EF would be better

Comment: not sure how your application is structured, but you can use SqlCommand or EF to do a direct insert into the target table, or use datatable/dataset to store all inputs then use bulk insert to insert them once (either using SqlBulkCopy or EF).

Comment: Unfortunately tutorials are too broad for SO. Documentation on [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) and [ADO.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/) are readily available.